# SQL View Definition - without scripting abilities

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I am looking for a way to give acces to information.schema including several sys views in SQL Server 2012.

Is there a way to restrict bieng able to *script out the definition* of the underlying objects, while only giving access to the metadata of the object?

Comment: you can give SELECT permission on view to avoid it. but how are you going to give non sysadmin access to system view and tables.

Comment: Don't know how, but they did it at my work so only the developers can see, and the analysis team cannot. sry not much help.